# Bind keys differently when in any minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

I normally use my keypad numbers to perform various navigation commands, but one of those commands is `goto-line`, and when I'm in the minibuffer entering the line number, I want my keypad to run `self-insert-command` instead of all those other commands.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set key bindings for the minibuffer in `minibuffer-local-map`. You can't bind a keypad key to `self-insert-command` because it's a function key, it doesn't have a character associated to it. It's possible to re-route function keys to characters, but this takes place at a lower level that isn't depend on the mode. You can get close by making the key invoke a macro.

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-add] "+")
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-subtract] "-")
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-multiply] "*")
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-divide] "/")
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-decimal] ".")
(dotimes (n 10)
  (define-key minibuffer-local-map (vector (make-symbol (format "kp-%d" n))) (format "%d" n)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [kp-1] "1")
```

---

Alternatively, it is possible to do the translation at a lower level as well. You have to write a custom event translation function and check whether the code is running in a minibuffer inside the translation function.

```
(defvar event-translate-keypad-characters
  '((kp-0 . ?0)
    (kp-1 . ?1)
    (kp-2 . ?2)
    (kp-3 . ?3)
    (kp-4 . ?4)
    (kp-5 . ?5)
    (kp-6 . ?6)
    (kp-7 . ?7)
    (kp-8 . ?8)
    (kp-9 . ?9)
    (kp-add . ?+)
    (kp-subtract . ?-)
    (kp-multiply . ?*)
    (kp-divide . ?/)
    (kp-decimal . ?.)))
(defun event-translate-keypad-character-in-minibuffer (_ignore-prompt)
  "In a minibuffer, transform a keypad event into the corresponding character.
Outside of a minibuffer, preserve the original event."
  (let* ((current-events (this-command-keys-vector))
     (current-event (aref current-events (1- (length current-events))))
     (translation (and (minibufferp)
               (assq current-event event-translate-keypad-characters))))
    (vector (if translation
        (cdr translation)
          current-event))))
(dolist (translation event-translate-keypad-characters)
  (define-key input-decode-map (vector (car translation))
              'event-translate-keypad-character-in-minibuffer))
```

Comment: (There are also other minibuffer keymaps, such as `minibuffer-local-completion-map` and its children, and the children of `minibuffer-local-map`.)